# Formatted "boot" partition by accident

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot-partition

I have Arch Linux and Windows 7 on the same HDD (actually, it's SSD). During re installation of Windows 7 I have, by accident, formatted my /boot partition for Arch Linux. It's only 200 MBs, but as far I know I can't boot Arch anymore (not without /boot partition for sure).

Is there a way to preserve my Arch installation by, somehow, re installing only data from /boot partition? How to do it? Please help!

P.S. I don't know if it matters, but beside "/boot", my Arch has other partitions: "/", "/var" and "/home"

Comment: Just restore from a backup. That's what they're for.

Comment: Khm... no backup :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the partition is still present, you should be able to boot the livecd, create a filesystem on the partition (`mkfs -t ext2 /dev/<partition>`), mount your arch partitions and then just `pacstrap /mnt <your-bootloader>`, and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Arch, but with debian i would try the following steps:

- Boot a live system from cd/dvd/usb-stick with the same architektur (32bit/64bit)
- Mount the partitions from the ssd
- `chroot` to the system on the ssd
- reinstall the kernel package(s)
- update the bootmanager (likely `grub`)